# Is there a way to hide a piece of content in a node if the current user is not friends with the author?

Tags: nodes, flags

Is there a way to hide a piece of content in a node if the current user is not friends with the author?

Basically I want to hide a piece of content or flag if the current user is not friends with the author. I've used [Flag Friend](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag_friend) module for the friends system.

Comment: I believe RULES module can help to achieve this. It integrates well with Flag API which is the basis of Flag Friend module.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply and thank you for your answer. Sorry but let me rephrase the question, I wanted to do it programmatically. Here is the code I found on the net but I cant seem to get it to work:                                                                                      <?php
global $user;
global $flag;
$flag = flag_get_flag('friend');
 if ((flag_friend_determine_friend_status($flag, $node->uid, $user->uid) == FLAG_FRIEND_FLAGGED)) {
   print "You have access";
    }
   else print "only friend access";
?>

Comment: Hai,did you check what value is returned when you print "flag_friend_determine_friend_status($flag, $node->uid, $user->uid)" ?